Loading OpenSSH public private keys into CryptoPP
I want to load openssh public key and private key using CryptoPP lib, the code is as follows:
#include <cryptopp/files.h>
#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <exception>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey private_key;
        {
            CryptoPP::FileSource file{"/root/.ssh/id_rsa", true};
            private_key.BERDecodePrivateKey(file, false, -1);
        }
        CryptoPP::FileSink sink{"/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", true};
        CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey{private_key}.DEREncode(sink);
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

The private key content is as follows:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
...shortened for brevity...
IjZsS/BX+GGUKLAAAAEXJvb3RANTYwNDdhMDExOWI1AQ==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

and public key is:
ssh-rsa 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 root@56047a0119b5

Since the Cryptopp official website is down, I cannot find any documents or instructions, does anyone know how to read openssh key files and convert them to CryptoPP:::RSA::PrivateKey and CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey?

You are barking up the wrong tree, I'm afraid. Despite having "RSA" in the name, OpenSSH keys use a non-standard format after you undo the PEM encoding.

Your header line of RSA key is for OpenSSH, you need to generate one key with openssl and then retry.

Your best bet is to look at the Portable OpenSSH implementation and find a way to extract the necessary components for CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey::Initialize (or the other constructor..)

Credit where credit is due, I got the hint to look at portable openssh from (a site linked from) this answer
